# Teams sort method is lost when changing the page

Tags: bug, status-completed, old-teams

When I sort the teams by number of members or by name the first page is actually correct, but for the following pages I get a list sorted by creation date in both cases. Sorting directly by creation date seems to give no problems.

[image]

The problem is that the pagination buttons at the bottom change the sort method using the key "tab", whereas the actual sorting buttons at the top use the key "sort" in the URL.

Comment: I miss meta bounties.

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in the next build, thanks for the report!