# Cannot access second teams page sorted by members

Tags: bug, old-teams

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/teams
2. Click on the [members tab](https://stackoverflow.com/teams?sort=members).
3. Scroll down, click on [page 2](https://stackoverflow.com/teams?page=2&tab=members).

What is now displayed is the second page of teams, but sorted by creation date/on the created tab.

Expected behavior: Display the second page of teams sorted by members/on the members tab.

Experienced on Chrome 48.0.2564.116 (Fedora 23), reproduced on FireFox 44.0.2, Vivaldi 1.0.344.37.

Comment: possible dupe: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317334/3933332